# How to find a file with a given string in several directories?

Tags: files, grep

I tried:

```
grep "6 0 1 1      0.4154" /media/linux/DATADISK/*
```

but it does not search in subdirectories of the directory DATADISK.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please do some research and read the documentation... Many commands do _not_ recursively process sub-directories unless explicitly directed to (usually, but not always, a -r or R flag). The documentation (`man grep` or `info grep`) should tell you how to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively) and [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux), the latter having the best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `grep`'s man page:

```
-r, --recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively,
          following symbolic links only if they are on the command
          line.
```

So `grep -r ...` will do the trick.  When `grep`ping multiple files I find it useful to also add `-H` so that the name of the matching file(s) is also printed (this is the default on Linux, but not on other platforms).

Comment: You probably want `-R` not `-r` since, as you explain, `-r` will not follow symlinks.